# Annotating the whole of a function declaration with a typealias

Tags: swift, function, types

My goal is to use a `typealias` as a one-word reminder “attached” to a function declaration. Say,

```
typealias VoidToVoid = () -> ()
```

I can use the type alias when stating the expected type of a closure, thus

```
let f : VoidToVoid = { return }
assert(f is VoidToVoid)
```

However, this does not seem the most usual way of declaring functions. I was hoping for a way to tell the reader that a function declared like `f′` below, should be of type `VoidToVoid`, and using that name.

(But *without* the reader having to infer, or to think, or to wait for the compiler to tell him or her about the type. Aggravating the situation, the compiler cannot know the type alias name I had wanted with `f′` and will likely output messages stating the bare type, not the alias.)

```
func f′() : VoidToVoid {  // tentative syntax
    return
}
```

Can I get there at all?

**Edit**: There are two ends at which the type alias is to be used. At one end, this is now possible:

```
func giveMeAClosure(_ f: VoidToVoid) {
    f()
}
```

At the other end, being `VoidToVoid` is implicit:

```
func canBeGivenAsClosure() {
    // ...
}
```

That is, where `canBeGivenAsClosure` is declared, it is true but not obvious that there is a connection between the two ends through `VoidToVoid`. This is different from the `let` case, which can have "`VoidToVoid`" as its type annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Closures are *unnamed* closure expressions, which is why we may use a function type `typealias` to specify the type of the closure, even for closures that have a non-empty argument list.

```
typealias VoidToVoid = () -> ()
typealias IntToVoid = (Int) -> ()

                  // unnamed closure expressions
let f: VoidToVoid = { print("foo") }
let g: IntToVoid  = { print($0) }
```

Note here that `f` and `g` in these exaples are *not functions*: they are simply immutable properties that holds references to (the backing storage of) the unnamed closures specified at the time of their declaration.

A function, one the other hand, is a special case of a closure; a closure with a name. Moreover, any function with a non-empty argument list needs to supply in internal (and optionally) and external parameter names *in its declaration*. A function type `typealias`, however, may not contain argument labels for its parameter names:

```
typealias IntToVoid = (a: Int) -> ()
/* Error: function types cannot have argument 
          label 'a'; use '_' instead */
```

This means that a function type `typealias` can't possible be used a substitute for the combined parameter and return type declaration part of a function (not even in the `() -> ()` case).

For details, see e.g.:

- [The Language Guide - Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

> **Closures**
>
> ...
>
> Global and nested functions, as introduced in [Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html), are actually
>   special cases of closures. Closures take one of three forms:
>
> - Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture any values.
> - Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture values from their enclosing function.
> - Closure expressions are unnamed closures written in a lightweight syntax that can capture values from their surrounding context.

---

On another note, you may naturally *test the type* of a given function to some existing function type `typealias`.

```
typealias VoidToVoid = () -> ()
typealias IntToVoid = (Int) -> ()

func f() -> () {}
func g(_ a: Int) -> () { _ = a }

print(f is VoidToVoid) // true
print(g is IntToVoid)  // true
```

Comment: Yet, from the point of view of types, two functions taking `Int` to `Void` can use all sorts of different names in their _function-name_ and _function-signature_ and still be passed as values to where an unnamed `IntToVoid` is expected. This is what I'd like to express.

Comment: @B98 first of all, note that closures are reference types, so neither functions nor unnamed closures are passed by value, but rather by reference. As I understood you question, you'd like to use a function type `typealias` to fully replace the _function-signature_ of a function: which is not possible. Following the grammar of a func. decl., the _function-signature_ contains a _parameter-clause_, which in turn (for non-void) contains a _parameter-list_ with a number of _parameter_:s and the grammar for these **requires** a _local-parameter-name_, which may not be present in a `typealias`; ...

Comment: ... the `typealias` simple holds the value of the _type-annotation_ (the second required part) in each _parameter_.

Comment: I just want the function type as a single word, which in different circumstances is available through the `typealias` feature. The names of parameters do not matter, then. E.g., given `func g(f: IntToVoid)`, I want to attach “IntToVoid” to func decls whose value, a function, could be passed to `g`.

Comment: …i.e., irrespective of whether a func or closure is passed by copy or passed by reference.

Comment: @B98: I'm not sure I follow, as this is note really the case you've described in your question. You can naturally declare method (or a closure, for that part) which has a single argument that is a closure (of a specified type, e.g. `IntToVoid`). Both functions and closures could be passed to such a function, and this is a very common idiom (higher order functions) in Swift, but I can't see how this relate to what you query for in your answer. See [e.g. this gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/52636d9fc34ad1d14302442548a38dda).